# UpdateCursor Not Working

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm writing a short script that iterates over a list of feature classes and sets values for a specific field ("Contour_Type"), based on the values in two other fields ("Type" and "Depression"). **It seems my script does not pass the 'with arcpy.UpdateCursor(i) as cursor' line**. I've searched for an answer, but can't find anything that pertains to my issue.

EDIT: The following code now works!

```
inputloc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
arcpy.env.workspace = inputloc
inputfcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    for i in inputfcs:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(i,["Type","Depression", "Contour_Type"]) as cursor: 
            for typ, dep, con_typ in cursor:
                if typ == "Intermediate" and dep == "Yes":
                    arcpy.AddWarning("Adding Values..")
                    row = (typ, dep, "Intermediate_Depression")
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
                elif typ == "Index" and dep == "Yes":
                    row = (typ, dep, "Index_Depression")
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
                else:
                    row = (typ, dep, typ)
                    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: The "with" syntax is a Data Access cursor construct -- `with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor`

Comment: When presenting code snippets for help here I think it is usually best to do so without try/except statements because they can mask the errors that Python provides you.  Those errors are very helpful for future visitors to find when they encounter the same problem.

Comment: @PolyGeo This is useful advice, I'll keep it mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Vince mentioned in the comments, 'The "with" syntax is a Data Access cursor construct'.

You have a couple options:

Using the old version of update cursor:

```
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(i)
for row in cursor:
    if row.getValue("Type") == "Intermediate" and row.getValue("Depression") == "Yes":
    row.setValue("Contour_Type", "Intermediate_Depression")
    cursor.updateRow(row)
    ....
del cursor
```

Using the (faster) Data Access cursor (requires 10.1+):

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(i, ["Type", "Depression", "Contour_Type"]) as cursor:
    for type, dep, con_type in cursor:
        if type == "Intermediate" and dep == "Yes":
            row = (type, dep, "Intermediate_Depression")
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        elif type == "Index" and dep == "Yes":
            row = (type, dep, "Index_Depression")
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            row = (type, dep, type)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct.  That is because the old cursors do not implement the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to allow `with` statements.

Comment: Don't forget *cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(i)* really should be matched with a *del cursor* otherwise python will persistently lock the feature class which would cause problems renaming, moving or editing. When using *with arcpy.da...* the locks are released at the end of the block.

Comment: Good point Michael. I always add the `del cursor` after the `da` version as well. Does it matter?

Comment: It won't hurt anything to delete the `da` cursor object, but I believe Esri has logic built in to release the schema lock when the `__exit__` method is called when the cursor has exhausted itself from the `with` statement. In other words, when the `with` statement is finished, there shouldn't be any locks on the data from the cursor.

Comment: @EmilBrundage After some more research, I realized I was mixing the two different cursor constructs. Your answer clarifies this even more. I will try again at work tomorrow morning and update. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilBrundage With the Data Access method,  is it necessary to loop using the `type,dep,con_type` tuple? I like that method, but could I also use `for row in cursor:` and then set the field values using the field list index, e.g. `row[2] = "Intermediate_Depression"` ?

Comment: Nah Alec, it's not necessary, but I find it much more intuitive.